# FirebaseInstanceId adding an OnSuccessListener causes application to close crash without a stack trace

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am experiencing a problem when adding an `OnsuccessListener` to `FirebaseInstanceId`, the `Activity closes without any stack traces.
No exception is visible`.

Here is the code added to the Activities `"onCreate"` lifecycle method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //... snip

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String instanceIdToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();                
        }
    });
```

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: For logs, select `No filters` in dropdown logcat

Comment: The Logcat should show something about the crash.please address that.

Comment: I think the error is not related to Firebase at all... but I am keeping at it. I'll update  the results when I know more.